FCM Not Recieved Most of TImes for Chat App
I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send notifications to Android devices, but I'm experiencing issues where FCM notifications are not delivered instantly. Sometimes they are delayed by several minutes or are even missed entirely. I need the notifications to behave similar to WhatsApp, where messages are delivered immediately, even when the app is in the background or closed.
  const url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-name/messages:send';
    const notificationPayload = {
        message: {
            token: fcmToken,
            data: {
                type: type,
                title: title,
                message: message
            },
            android: {
                priority:"high"
            }

        }
    };
   

